# How to convert float to string using single char pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, floating-point

I got question like this:

```
char *ptr;
float f1 = 12.34;
```

Now using this char *ptr, I want to convert this float value to string, which can be displayed in printf using this pointer "ptr".

means:
12.34 ==> "12.34"

I need not to use any other pointer or temporary variable. I can not use `snprintf`.

Comment: c or c++? make up your mind please

Comment: You should always know, at all times, where your pointers point to. Where does `ptr` point to?

Comment: Is this homework? Why can't you use `snprintf()`?

Comment: @kapilddit try with `sprintf'

Comment: This question is like for curiosity and probably off topic. If you have enough resource then why you not use it? it's like type on screen with out using keyboard?  invention of keyboard for why?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to think the answers without using snprintf so I think any language is fine to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP tagged C++ so here goes..

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << f1;
std::string s = ss.str();
ptr = s.c_str();
```

Comment: Also: `std::to_string(f1)`

Comment: The question is tagged c and c++ and OP said *I need not to use any other pointer or temporary variable*.

Comment: LOL I can't believe my answer was accepted!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Use `snprintf` function to convert a `float` value to a string.</strike>

Use `sprintf` function to convert a `float` value to a string. Also use a field width to ensure you are not overflowing the destination array.

Comment: OP says that he can not use ``snprintf``

Comment: <quote> I can not use snprintf. </quote>

Comment: For some dramatic reason he "can not use snprintf"

Comment: i guess he's using the Windows VC++ compiler

Comment: Downvoters please explain the downvote, the question is tagged c and c++.

Comment: What buffer do you provide to sprintf? Remember no other pointer or temporary variable.

Comment: @NeilKirk I malloc and assign the result to the `char *ptr`. This follows OP requirements.